# Why doesn't my operational integrator work?

Tags: integrator, operational-amplifier

Here is the schematic I'm following, to build an operational integrator.

[image: schematic]

([Image source - Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_6.html))

I'm using a LM358N IC which has 2 op amps. Below is a crude drawing of my connections.

I don't seem to get what I want, when I feed a square wave signal 0 to 5 V with a 20 ms period. I expect a negative sloped signal, but just get 0 V output.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: connection diagram]

Comment: What are the component values R and C?

Comment: How do you reset the cap?

Comment: R = .4 MOhms C = 47 MicroF

Comment: I didn't. Do I have to?? I also tried to make a Inverting Amplifier and it also didn't work...

Comment: If I change my input voltage signal to -1 to 1 V square wave would I need one?

Comment: I'll upload an image I captured on my oscilloscope. I have a small signal but I expected a sloped signal

Comment: Bias the positive input of the opamp at VCC/2 with a resistive divider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcnZs8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The op-amp output cannot go negative unless there is a negative supply to the op-amp.*

Comment: Ok, but why do I see a positive output when I applied a positive input signal to the invertinv terminals

Comment: If you are feeding the input with +5 V and with no DC path in the feedback then you are probably pushing the input outside the common-mode input range (0 V to V+ −1.5 V) at 25°C. When you do that anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic problems with that circuit.

- You are applying a positive voltage to an inverting configuration. The op-amp needs to provide a negative output value n response for which it needs a negative supply.
- you don’t have a dc feedback pathway. Without DC feedback (1) your op-amp operating point is not defined and (2) op-amp bias currents will be integrated driving the output even with no input.

To fix the former, either use a negative supply, or bias the positive input above ground.

If this is the totality of your circuit, to fix the latter, add a large resistor in parallel with the capacitor which effectively turns the configuration into a low-pass filter. This behaves as an integrator for signals above the cut-off frequency.

DC integrators require additional circuitry to set their DC bias. Either switches that periodically discharge the capacitor, or external circuitry that reacts to the output and changes the input accordingly (e.g., in an oscillator configuration).